# how to write a piecewise function in one line

Tags: functions

I have a piecewise function $f(x)$, it takes up too much space, I want to conserve space when writing it. Is there a practical and professional way to write it in a single line, so I save some space?
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
  a,  & x = 0 \\
  b,  & x = 1 \\
  c,  & x \neq 0,1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I have voted to close this question as off-topic, because it is not about mathematics (it is about typesetting, really).  You might be better off asking at [tex.se].

Comment: @XanderHenderson It has more to do with formalism of math expression, but math nonetheless I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's common to use $1_A(x)$ to denote $1_A(x) = 1$ for $x\in A$ and $=0$ everywhere else. Hence, we can rewrite $f$ as $f(x) = a1_{0} +b1_{1} + c1_{\{0,1\}^c}$

Comment: Fantastic answer @Andrew Yuan by using characteristic functions. +1 for that.